# directory structure problems with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, path, directory

I have a directory structure:

```
/Users/Eamon/Sites:
  -js
    application.js
  -reqscripts
    jquery.js
  -templates
    login_success.php
    logout.php
checklogin.php
checkreglogin.php
index.php
```

I am setting up a simple login system. Upon login, I get an "Object not found!" 404 error. I know I am doing something wrong (in a few places...probabaly) with regards to referencing the directory structure...just not sure how to remedy it. It probably has to do with adding something like "../" to the beginning of the path where I am referencing the directory structure. I know this is the problem because when I login - the url in the browser reads:

`localhost/~Eamon/login_success.php`

This is not where the file is located according to my above directory structure! Here is some code:

**EDIT** (added all of index.php)

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>it IT</title>
<script src="reqscripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/application.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="login" method="post" action="checklogin.php">
    <h1>Member Login</h1>
    <p>Username:<input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></p>
    <p>Password:<input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
</form>
<form name="register" method="post" action="checkreglogin.php">
    <h1>Member Registration</h1>
    <p>Username:<input name="rmyusername" type="text" id="rmyusername"></p>
    <p>Password:<input name="rmypassword" type="password" id="rmypassword"></p>
    <p>Email:<input name="myemail" type="text" id="myemail"></p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Register">
</form>
<div id="showuser"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Check the "action" tag path...is this correct?**

Is the link path right in the above file?

js/application.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#login").submit(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('checklogin.php', $(this).serialize(), function(){
            $("#showuser").load("templates/login_success.php");
            $("#login").remove();
            $("#register").remove();
        });
    });

    $("#register").submit(function(e) {  
        e.preventDefault();
        $.post('checkreglogin.php', $(this).serialize(), function(){
            $("#showuser").load("templates/login_success.php");
            $("#login").remove();
            $("#register").remove();
        });
    });
});
```

Help me!

Answer (score 0):

in templates/logout.php you should put ../ as the link href. This because when you click the logout link in the login_success file you enter the template directory. So index.php is no more in the same directory as your location.

Another strange thing is the "session_destroy()" in templates/login_success.php... if you destroy the session you automatically logout the just logged user.

Comment: thanks mir...ill give it a shot...I also use session_destroy at the end of my checklogin and checkreglogin scripts. These scripts run the neccessary operations to check if a user is logged in...and store data in the user database - should I be doing this?

Comment: I think I am doing the same thing wrong in my index.php file in the "action=" tag. I'll post the whole file in an update above.